# In andengine collision is getting fired on a detached Entity

Tags: java, android, andengine

// playerBall extends Animate class

//Even after entity becomes invisible,collision is detected

Collision occurs at the point where entity was before getting detached.

```
private void ballsR(){

              registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());
              Random r = new Random();
              int i= r.nextInt(7)+1;

          if(count<1){
         ballForColl[0] = ball;
          count++;
          System.out.println(count);
          }
          registerUpdateHandler(this.ballsDet = new TimerHandler(5.0f,true, new ITimerCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                /* ball.setVisible(false);
                 ball.setIgnoreUpdate(true);
                  ball.detachSelf();
                  ball.clearUpdateHandlers();
                  @override*/
            resourcesManager.engine.runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                            /* Now it is save to remove the entity! */
                            //pScene.detachChild(SpriteRemoveExample.this.mFaceToRemove);
                        detachChild((ball));
                        ball.setIgnoreUpdate(true);
                    }
            });


                //  detachChild(ball);

             //  unregisterUpdateHandler(ball) ;                
            }
        }));
```

/****************************************************************/

//my player ball class

```
     public playerBall(final float pX, final float pY, final TiledTextureRegion pTextureRegion,VertexBufferObjectManager vbom) {
         super(pX, pY, pTextureRegion,vbom);
         this.mPhysicsHandler= new PhysicsHandler(this);
         this.registerUpdateHandler(this.mPhysicsHandler);
        this.mPhysicsHandler.setVelocity(DEMO_VELOCITY, DEMO_VELOCITY);

        // System.out.println("this is srs1");
 }
     @Override
     protected void onManagedUpdate(final float pSecondsElapsed) {
             if(this.mX < 0) {
                // System.out.println("this is srs");
                     this.mPhysicsHandler.setVelocityX(DEMO_VELOCITY);

             } else if(this.mX + this.getWidth() > 800) {
                     this.mPhysicsHandler.setVelocityX(-DEMO_VELOCITY);
             }

             if(this.mY < 0) {
                     this.mPhysicsHandler.setVelocityY(DEMO_VELOCITY);
             } else if(this.mY + this.getHeight() > 480) {
                     this.mPhysicsHandler.setVelocityY(-DEMO_VELOCITY);
             }

             super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
     }


}
```

Comment: If you can't even take the time to format your code, let alone form a question, no one is going to take the time to help you

Comment: Please improve your question format.

Comment: I am sorry for bad format. This is my first question on stackoverflow. I was not familiar with the formatting.

Comment: read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

What is "ball"? is it an Sprite, AnimatedSprite, Circle...
Does it contain a Body?

If the latter is true, you're probably forgetting to remove it from the physics world...

Try this:

```
final PhysicsConnector physicsConnector =
physicsWorld.getPhysicsConnectorManager().findPhysicsConnectorByShape(shape);

    mEngine.runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() 
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            if (physicsConnector != null)
            {
                 physicsWorld.unregisterPhysicsConnector(physicsConnector);
                 body.setActive(false);
                 physicsWorld.destroyBody(bbody);
                 scene.detachChild(shape);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I am not using physics world. ball is a playerBall object. Player ball extends AnimatedSprite. I am using physicshandler to provide velocity in playerBall class.